# Encrypting Images in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using  azure blob  storage to store few images and their metadata (using the  metadata  property of blob) .
Beacuse the data is sensitive ,I need to encrypt these images such that no one even with proper access to container should be able  to view the actual image
The person with proper access could only see an encrypted file. I would decrypt the images after downloading the file
What would be an appropriate solution to this .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335565/encrypting-image-data-before-uploading-to-azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look of below doc.

This is how to encrypt and upload:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault#encrypt-blob-and-upload

This is how to decrypt and download:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault#decrypt-blob-and-download

Let me know whether you can work it out.:)

Comment: This completely works.   
So along with image I'm also adding metadata for the image , with this solution the image is getting encrypted but the metadata remains unencrypted. Though
I can encrypt the metadata prior to  uploading image, but is there a way this can be achieved using azure services